# Vertically aligning a node joining subgraphs in Graphviz

Tags: alignment, graphviz, dot

I give the following input to Dot:

```
digraph G {
  subgraph cluster1 {
    fontsize = 20;
    label = "Group 1";
    A -> B -> C -> D;
    style = "dashed";
  }

  subgraph {
    O [shape=box];
  }

  subgraph cluster2 {
    fontsize = 20;
    label = "Group 2";
    Z -> Y -> X -> W [dir=back];
    style = "dashed";
  }

  D -> O [constraint=false];
  W -> O [constraint=false, dir=back];
}
```

And it produces:

[image: picture with node O aligned with A and Z]

How can I align node `O` so that it has the same rank as `D` and `W`? That is, a graph that looks like:

```
A   Z
|   |
B   Y
|   |
C   X
|   |
D-O-W
```

Adding

```
 { rank=same; D; O; W; }
```

yields the error

```
Warning: D was already in a rankset, ignored in cluster G
Warning: W was already in a rankset, ignored in cluster G
```

I'm thinking I can hack it by adding invisible nodes and edges to the subgraph of `O`, but I was wondering if I was missing some Dot magic.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use an approach with `rankdir=LR` and use `constraint=false` for the edges inside the clusters:

```
digraph G {
  rankdir=LR;

  subgraph cluster1 {
    fontsize = 20;
    label = "Group 1";
    rank=same;
    A -> B -> C -> D [constraint=false];
    style = "dashed";
  }

  subgraph cluster2 {
    fontsize = 20;
    label = "Group 2";
    rank=same;
    Z -> Y -> X -> W [dir=back, constraint=false];
    style = "dashed";
  }

  O [shape=box];
  D -> O -> W;
}
```

It's not dot magic :-), but it achieves this:

[image: graphviz output with rankdir LR]

Hacking with invisible nodes does also work:

```
digraph G {
  subgraph cluster1 {
    fontsize = 20;
    label = "Group 1";
    A -> B -> C -> D;
    style = "dashed";
  }

  subgraph {
    O1[style=invis];
    O2[style=invis];
    O3[style=invis];
    O [shape=box];

    O1 -> O2 -> O3 -> O [style=invis];
  }

  subgraph cluster2 {
    fontsize = 20;
    label = "Group 2";
    Z -> Y -> X -> W [dir=back];
    style = "dashed";
  }

  edge[constraint=false];
  D -> O -> W;
}
```

The result is almost identical:

[image: graphviz output with invisible nodes]

Comment: Thanks for the prompt and informative reply! I originally hacked it with invisible nodes, but have switched to the first solution. Feels more elegant and works perfectly.